# Strongswan VPN not working unless pinging out manually

Tags: vpn, google-cloud, strongswan

We have successfully set up a strongswan vpn on our network to communicate with Google Cloud VPN.

Sometimes we leave it idle for a while, let's say a night, that's when the issue appear.
If I try to ping from Google to our network, it doesn't work, no packets are transmitted.
If I try to ping from our side to Google, it works, and then the ping which was blocked on Google side starts working fine.

It looks like StrongSwan enters in sleep mode on our side and wakes up only when I manually ping out, not when receiving packets.
But I can't find any option in the doc to fix this, has anyone got this issue and fixed it somehow?

EDIT: there is no firewall on our side which could explain this behaviour and on google side we can only set the IP range allowed to go through the firewall, nothing else. But since it uses their own VPN service to communicate with our strongswan server, I strongly doubt it comes from them.

Here is what ipsec status returns before the issue on our side:

```
net-net[72]: ESTABLISHED 113 minutes ago, 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[79.xxx.xxx.xxx]...146.xxx.xxx.xxx[146.xxx.xxx.xxx]     
net-net{255}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 24, ESP SPIs: c5xxxxxx 4exxxxxx     
net-net{255}:   192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24 === 10.132.0.0/20
```

Here is what ipsec statusall returns after:

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.3.5, Linux 4.4.0-64-generic, x86_64):  
uptime: 22 days, since Feb 27 15:21:33 2017  
malloc: sbrk 2568192, mmap 0, used 370288, free 2197904  
worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 11  
loaded plugins: charon aes agent attr connmark constraints dnskey fips-prf gcm md4 openssl pem pgp pkcs1 pkcs12 pkcs7 pkcs8 pubkey rc2 resolve revocation sshkey test-vectors x509 xcbc sha1 sha2 md5 gmp random nonce hmac stroke kernel-netlink socket-default updown

Listening IP addresses:  192.168.17.205  79.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connections:     
    net-net:  79.xxx.xxx.xxx...146.xxx.xxx.xxx  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s     
    net-net:   local:  [79.xxx.xxx.xxx] uses pre-shared key authentication     
    net-net:   remote: [146.xxx.xxx.xxx] uses pre-shared key authentication     
    net-net:   child:  192.168.17.0/24 192.168.0.0/24 === 10.132.0.0/20 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):     
    net-net[72]: ESTABLISHED 2 hours ago, 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[79.xxx.xxx.xxx]...146.xxx.xxx.xxx[146.xxx.xxx.xxx]     
    net-net[72]: IKEv2 SPIs: 0fd4efxxxxxx 17ed000axxxxxx*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 108 minutes     
    net-net[72]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048     
    net-net{255}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 24, ESP SPIs: c5b822fe_i 4ed83bd8_o     
    net-net{255}:  AES_GCM_16_128, 3916 bytes_i (47 pkts, 1020s ago), 3956 bytes_o (47 pkts, 1020s ago), rekeying in 7 hours     
    net-net{255}:   192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24 === 10.132.0.0/20
```

And the ipsec.conf:

```
config setup

conn %default
        ikelifetime=24h
        keylife=8h
        rekeymargin=9m
        keyingtries=1
        authby=psk
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no
        esp=aes128gcm16-modp2048!
        dpdaction=restart
conn net-net
        left=79.xxx.xxx.xxx
        leftsubnet=192.168.17.0/24,192.168.0.0/24
        leftid=79.xxx.xxx.xxx
        leftfirewall=yes
        leftdns=xxx....
        right=146.xxx.xxx.xxx
        rightsubnet=10.132.0.0/20
        rightid=146.xxx.xxx.xxx
        auto=start
```

And on the logs from the google side I noticed that at the moment I send the ping test, it sends some requests to recreate CHILD_SA:

```
"creating rekey job for CHILD_SA ESP/0xxxxxxxxx/79.xxx.xxx.xxx"  
...
```

Once the CHILD_SA is established with its SPI the ping goes through.
Though the ESP SPI didn't change before and after.
I also see rekeying in 7 hours on ipsec statusall. Could it be the issue that during the night there is no activity during more than 7 hours?

Here is charon log:

```
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 11[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA request 223 [ N(REKEY_SA) SA No KE TSi TSr ]
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 11[IKE] CHILD_SA net-net{255} established with SPIs c5b8xxxxxxx_o and TS 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24 === 10.132.0.0/20
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 11[ENC] generating CREATE_CHILD_SA response 223 [ SA No KE TSi TSr ]
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 05[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI 7dd6xxxx
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 05[IKE] closing CHILD_SA net-net{254} with SPIs ce7xxxx (95264 bytes) 7ddxxxxx (4885433 bytes) and TS 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24 === 10.132.0.0/20
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 05[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI ce75xxxxx
Mar 22 07:56:43 vpn07 charon: 05[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
```

And google logs:

```
D  sending DPD request 
D  CHILD_SA closed 
D  received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI cexxxxx 
D  parsed INFORMATIONAL response 224 [ D ] 
D  received packet: from 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (76 bytes) 
D  sending packet: from 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (76 bytes) 
D  generating INFORMATIONAL request 224 [ D ] 
D  sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI 7dxxxxxx
I  closing CHILD_SA vpn_79.xxx.xxx.xxx{33} with SPIs 7dxxxxx (5073648 bytes) cexxxxxx (95264 bytes) and TS 10.132.0.0/20 === 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24  
I  CHILD_SA vpn_79.xxx.xxx.xxx{34} established with SPIs 4exxxxxx c5xxxxxx and TS 10.132.0.0/20 === 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24  
D  handling HA CHILD_SA vpn_79.xxx.xxx.xxx{34} 10.132.0.0/20  === 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.17.0/24  (segment in: 1*, out: 1*) 
D  parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 223 [ SA No KE TSi TSr ] 
D  received packet: from 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (476 bytes) 
D  sending packet: from 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (620 bytes) 
D  generating CREATE_CHILD_SA request 223 [ N(REKEY_SA) SA No KE TSi TSr ] 
I  establishing CHILD_SA vpn_79.xxx.xxx.xxx{1} 
D  creating rekey job for CHILD_SA ESP/0xxxxxxx/79.xxx.xxx.xxx 
D  parsed INFORMATIONAL response 222 [ ] 
D  received packet: from 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (76 bytes) 
D  sending packet: from 146.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 79.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (76 bytes) 
D  generating INFORMATIONAL request 222 [ ] 
D  sending DPD request
```

Comment: Try to provide more information. The configs, status output, firewall rules. In particular, the status of the connection (`ipsec statusall`, on both sides) if this happens (before pinging from your side). Also, check the strongSwan log, look especially at what happens if you start pinging from your side.

Comment: What is your `dpdtimeout `? What happens if you  add `dpddelay = 10s
 ; dpdtimeout = 60s`

Comment: thanks for your time. Please see edits in the post.
dpdtimeout is not set in the ipsec.conf
I  put the conf in the edit too

Comment: The status output you posted seems to be from after the already pinged from your side and the rekeying created a new CHILD_SA. How does it look before that? And what's happening if you ping from the other end (on either side)? You seem to have access to the log on the Google side, is there more from there, e.g. status output when the problem occurs?

Comment: sorry you are right, I've added google logs and the ipsec status from before.
If I ping from my side it is not working, and miraculously gets unblocked after approx 30s-1min.
On google side I can ping without issue and then it unblocks the incoming packets.
There is no status output on google logs. I can only get more info for each line I have pasted above if you need (it is too much to put so better you ask me which line should be expanded)

Comment: The status output is still from after the rekeying (same unique IDs and SPIs). And didn't you write the exact opposite in your original question (i.e. pinging from your side makes blocked pings on the Google side work, now you say pings from the Google side make the blocked pings from your side work). Anyway, looks like they are using the [_ha_ plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/HighAvailability) ("handling HA CHILD_SA...") could be a problem with that.

Comment: we checked and the SPI and ID haven't changed despite the rekeying.
You are right, pinging from google side is blocked, not from ours.
As I am running a lot of terminals it is quite confusing sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Strongswan VPN client is behind a firewall or a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) device which, after a moment of inactivity, drops the "connection" (it's probably UDP here, the term "connection" is not a good choice). Any incoming data belonging to that connection is then considered as invalid and is dropped (you may have a line about this in your FW/NAT device logs). Later, when you ping Google from the inside, your connection is re-established and your firewall/NAT device now considers again incoming data as valid.

The solution is to prevent your firewall/NAT device from dropping the "connection" by ensuring a regular data stream (one UDP message every minute may be enough). Search for any keep-alive mechanism built in Strongswan and activate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is actually no firewall on our side (google has its own but since we ping out successfully it shouldn't be the blocking part)

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Your subnet on your side is 192.168.17.0/24 which is a private range. That means there is a box on the way that does NAT. This is also what I call a firewall. The box won't accept any incoming UDP frames that does not belong to an existing connection previously established from the inside. I will amend my answer.

Comment: The "point of entry" of the subnet has no firewall though. But I understand your point, it could be the one dropping the connection. Unfortunately this is not the case as DPD messages are sent every 30s, meaning the peer is alive.

Comment: we finally found the root cause. Despite having a public ip communicating directly with the vpn, the machine, being a virtual machine, was forced to go through the firewall. The DPD requests are sent from a different port than the VPN packets, therefore the connection for them, when idle for too long, was closed by the firewall. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentTeyssier You're welcome. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario where this behavior can occur is when IPv6 packets are used at the network layer. That is obviously not the case here.

However, I have experienced exactly the same behavior even without using NAT, but with IPv6.

Internet routers have packet filtering capabilities that prevent unrestricted access to a local host with a public IPv6 address. When using IPSec tunnels over IPv6, the router may block packets from the outside after a few minutes of inactivity, even though both tunnel endpoints indicate a proper security association. This is because the connection is controlled via UDP, but the payload is transported via ESP. While the control channel is regularly used because of rekeying or DPD (dead peer detection), it can be silent on the transport channel. This causes the Internet router to assume that there is no more traffic on the transport channel. Thus, the router blocks further incoming packets.

To fix this problem, it is necessary to expose the internal host. Depending on the capabilities to configure packet filtering on the router, it is sufficient to allow incoming ESP traffic for the host.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).